# How to convert row vector to column vector in Eigen?

Tags: c++, eigen

The [documentation](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TutorialMatrixClass.html) says:

> ... in Eigen, vectors are just a special case of
>   matrices, with either 1 row or 1 column. The case where they have 1
>   column is the most common; such vectors are called column-vectors,
>   often abbreviated as just vectors. In the other case where they have 1
>   row, they are called row-vectors.

However this program outputs unintuitive results:

```
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Dense>
#include <iostream>

typedef Eigen::Matrix<double, 1, Eigen::Dynamic> RowVector;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    RowVector row(10);
    std::cout << "Rows: "    << row.rows() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Columns: " << row.cols() << std::endl;
    row.transposeInPlace();
    std::cout << "Rows: "    << row.rows() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Columns: " << row.cols() << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
Rows: 1
Columns: 10
Rows: 1
Columns: 10
```

Is this a bug, or am I using the library incorrectly?

Comment: I added an assert to the development branch of Eigen to guard against this (mis)use.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The documentation for `transposeInPlace` says:

> **Note**
>
> if the matrix is not square, then `*this` must be a resizable matrix.

You'll need your type to have both dynamic rows and columns:

```
Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic>
```

However, there's already a `typedef` for this: `MatrixXd`.

Alternatively, if you still want the compile-time sizes, you can use `tranpose` rather than `transposeInPlace` to give you a new transposed matrix rather than modify the current one:

```
typedef Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, 1> ColumnVector;
ColumnVector column = row.transpose();
```